# R Shiny: How do I use nearPoints on a geom_area or stacked geom_bar?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use hover tooltips on a geom_area, but I can't get them to work with that geometry.  It only displays lowest set of grouped variables (in the example below, it will show 'Lakers' hover values, but not 'Celtics'.

Interestingly, if you replace the geom_area with, for example, geom_point, the code below works fine.  But for the real dashboard I'm making, an area chart is necessary.

```
library("shiny")
library("ggplot2")

d <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03",
                                 "2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03")),
                team = c("Celtics", "Celtics", "Celtics",
                         "Lakers", "Lakers", "Lakers"),
                points_scored = c(108, 89, 95, 78, 93, 82))

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
      plotOutput("graph", 
                 hover = hoverOpts("plot_hover", delay = 100, delayType = "debounce")),
      uiOutput("hover_info")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(d, aes(x = date, y = points_scored, fill = team)) +
      geom_area()
  })

  output$hover_info <- renderUI({
    hover <- input$plot_hover
    point <- nearPoints(d, hover, threshold = 5, maxpoints = 1, addDist = TRUE)
    if (nrow(point) == 0) return(NULL)

    wellPanel(
      paste0(point$team, " - ", point$date, ": ", point$points_scored)
    )
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Thanks in advance!

--- Edit ---

It's actually displaying the hover in the incorrect location.  See the attached picture.  It treats the point (Celtics on Jan 1) as if it's still at y = 108. I want it to hover at the top of the visible red bar (108 + 78 = 186), but still display 108.

[image: hover example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a sketchy workaround, but it makes the app do what I want it to do.  My edited app only edits the server function, and goes something like this:

- Continue to use the main dataframe 'd' to generate the graph. Continue to use the hover in plotOutput off of that graph
- Create a workaround dataframe 'd_workaround' that is identical, except it contains 1) the actual y position of the points in a column with the same name as the y column in 'd' and the graph (points_scored. I wanted to name this 'position', but the app only worked if it had the same name as the y column in 'd') and 2) the 'real' value that I want my tooltip to display (points_scored_real)
- Direct my nearPoints() to use d_workaround, and my tooltips to display points_scored_real from that column

The app looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

d <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03",
                                 "2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03")),
                team = c("Celtics", "Celtics", "Celtics",
                         "Lakers", "Lakers", "Lakers"),
                points_scored = c(108, 89, 95, 78, 93, 82))

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("graph", 
               hover = hoverOpts("plot_hover", delay = 100, delayType = "debounce")),
    uiOutput("hover_info")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(d, aes(x = date, y = points_scored, fill = team)) +
      geom_area()
  })

  output$hover_info <- renderUI({
    d_workaround <- d %>% 
      spread(team, points_scored) %>% 
      mutate(Celtics = str_c(Celtics + Lakers, "-", Celtics),
             Lakers = str_c(Lakers, "-", Lakers)) %>% 
      gather(team, points_scored, Celtics, Lakers) %>% 
      separate(points_scored, c("points_scored", "points_scored_real"), convert = TRUE)

    hover <- input$plot_hover
    point <- nearPoints(d_workaround, hover, threshold = 10, maxpoints = 1, addDist = TRUE)
    if (nrow(point) == 0) return(NULL)

    wellPanel(
      paste0(point$team, " - ", point$date, ": ", point$points_scored_real)
    )
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```